# php find a stack of time

Tags: php, intervals

I need to find If $now(00:00:00) if included from $a and $b

```
echo $a= date('H:i:s', strtotime("23:00:00"));

echo $now = date('H:i:s', time("now");*(es.00:00:00)*

echo $b=date('H:i:s', strtotime("01:00:00"));

if ($now>$a && $now<$b) {echo "si";} else {echo "no";}
```

output say: no

__________________EDIT____________________________

Ok thanks to all, I think give you more information:

I read with php an file .xml, from this file, I get some information about program in tv, with :

-the name of program, -name of channel, -and time to program start in this format (20151210004500 +0100)

I think at this point is more easy to use this format, or not?

I would find in array from .xml the program on air, for make this I must compared the date and time in this format, It is possible?

Can you help me?

Sorry for my poor english, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `strtotime` before comparation

```
if(strtotime($now) > strtotime($a) && strtotime($now) < strtotime($b)     
{ 
    // do your staff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = new DateTime;
$a = (new DateTime)->setTime(23, 0, 0);

if ($now > $a && $now < $a->modify('+2 hours')) {
    echo 'si';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do by using [time() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) to get the current time in numeric format (seconds from the 1970-1-1).

Than you can convert your dates into the same time format with [strtotime() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$now = time();
$a = strtotime("10 september 2010");
$b = strtotime("10 september 2020");

if( $now > $a && $now < $b )
    echo "Yes";
else
    echo "No";
```